# Custom css on top nav for specific page wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to wordpress theme development and I need to style the main navigation menu depending on what page the user is on.

Simply put, only the home page has a unique styling on it and all other pages will have a different css.  I have tried adding this in my functions.php but it does not work.

```
if (is_page( 52 ) ):
    wp_enqueue_style('style1_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style1.css' );
endif;
```

Sorry if its badly explained!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fixed it by adding
```

```html
nav <?php if ( is_page('52')) { echo 'class="homeNav"'; } ?>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php // TOP PICTURE DEFINITION FOR ARTICLES PAGE
        if ( is_page()) {
           wp_enqueue_style('style1_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style1.css' );
        }
?>
```

Use like this for detailed reference kindly refer this link [click_here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Comment: Thanks Sri, It turned out I just needed to reference a class within the original css file and didn't need a separate .css file.

Answer (score 2):

You can link one css file for all pages and use more specific selectors (with binging to  css-classes) for css ruling:

```css
  .nav {/* for all pages */
    ...
  }
 
  .home .nav { /* for home page */
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Target only the `home` class like:

```
.home .nav { 
 // CSS STUFF
}
```

And if you want all `nav` classes, use:

```
.nav { 
 // CSS STUFF
}
```

Comment: but my nav is in the header.php file, if I add a class to that it would be for every page